# What is the Gayatri mantra?

Tags: gayatri-mantra

I am a householder and want to know what is the exact Gayatri mantra which I can recite for my benifit without any guru initiation . Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recite the Saavitr Mantra given in Rig Veda 3.62.10:

> त्स॑वि॒तुर्वरे॑ण्यं॒ भर्गो॑ दे॒वस्य॑ धीमहि । धियो॒ यो न॑: प्रचो॒दया॑त् ॥

Avoid usage of the three MahaaVyahrtis at all costs, **they cannot be used without initiation**. Avoid the addition of Pranava in the front as well.

Just that Mantra here and nothing more. You can learn the pronunciation from a guru, if you cannot find one, it doesn't really matter as the mantras of the Rik are for all people and all Varnas (as opposed to the other Vedas), as I've been told by my guru.

You can learn the pronunciation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ2nYFnMiQk&ab_channel=VinnithPullavarayar

The Varaanasi Paatha is most accurate.

Make sure to follow cleanliness, and recite in a fairly good place/surrounding.

Make sure not to invoke Rshi or Chhanda as additional rules have to be followed for it.

Also, recite in the tri Sandhyaa period only (sunrise, noon, sunset).

Learn the meaning of the mantra, and recite with Bhaava that the meaning represents.

---

Avoid out-loud recitations, there's special rules to be followed for Vaachika Japa. Do whispered chanting (the sound doesn't reach beyond a meter or two) or mental, instead or, don't do Japa at all, and simply say it once, in each Sandhyaa.

The correct methodology utilizes water and Sandhyaa Vandanaa as well avoid those things as even more rules have to be followed for them. If you get into Sandhyaa Vandanaa, then you'll need to follow its rules, which requires bathing in ashes, mud, and water everytime... among other things.

Either don't do it at all, or do it the tiniest amount, if you try to escalate, then you WILL need to change to living in a village in a hut, spending 2 hours per day to follow all the rules. Not to mention Vishvadeva offerings and Yajnas which are deeply linked and almost required for Sandhyaa Vandana... that's 4 hours at-least, per day.

Comment: Arya samaj says that this mantra is for nirgun parambrham om and not surya dev. Can you prove it is for surya dev

Comment: Lol, I don't need to prove anything, they need to prove their claim. Savitr is a name of Surya. The Devataa of the mantra is also Savitaa (Surya). No proof is required, everyone who is not from a neo-hindu institution accepts this.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I have question why gayatri mantra has been given so importance unlike other mantras in vedas? ? ?

Comment: @Hope It's given more importance than others because of the effect. It purifies your actions. That's also why it's prescribed after committing a sin like masturbation for example. There's other mantras that purify the actions as well, all mantras with 4 worded sections do that. But, others have smaller (and different) effects due to various reasons, so this is the best. Your efforts are the only things you can control, you can't control your wealth or family, so that's why it's important. It directly changes your character for the better in every way.

Comment: @DadAnonymous Savitaa is the nominative noun for Savitr. They both refer to the same MALE Aaditya. All the 12 Aadityas can be simplified to the one Surya. Although, most things can be simplified into the rule of the Dirgha vowel ending in names to be equivalent to feminine, it's not the case in this instance. Saavitrii is feminine, Savitaa is not. There's more nuance here as Savitaa in a certain context is feminine, but essentially, Savitaa = Surya (at-least, one form of him).

Comment: @Hope even Sayanacharya Considered Savita as Atman/Parmeshwar in this mantra

Answer (score 1):

Gayatri is a chhand, generally savita mantr is known as gayatri mantr.
it is found in Rigved samhita, Yajurved samhita and samved samhita.
Whole mantr is found in Shukl yajurved madhyandina samhita 36.3.
You need initiation from a guru to recite any mantr, if possible get the initiation from any guru, or just go to any Arya samaj mandir they will guide you regarding this.